# How to get SUM of f3 but Grouped by f2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get all comments count grouped by category. eg

```
f1      f2      f3
php     hello   34
php     hello   34
php     hello   34
php     world   23
php     world   23
php     world   23
asp     world1   43
asp     world1  43
asp     world1   43
```

How to get sum of f3 but grouped by f2?

So not 34 + 34 + 34 +23 ... but 34 + 23 + 43

EDIT: f2 is unique

Comment: You mean grouped by `f1`?  Grouped by `f2` would be `34+34+34` and `23+23+23+43+43+43`

Comment: No, if we group by f2, we get 34 + 23 + 43 and all I need is sum this

Comment: In your sample data `f2` is NOT unique.  Can you show some actual data please?

Comment: Wouldn't the real question be **why** those values are three times in your database ?

Comment: could you make an export of your db and copy it in [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) ?

Comment: I want to get sum of invalid votes.

Comment: QV is UNIQUE so grouping by QV would give me value of invalid votes by foreach QV. I want to sum them all so I can Get ALL invalid votes

Comment: Dont be bad at me, this is the db I found here, very bad designed. Everythin is on one table. I'm just trying to get some reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I thought it all over.. and basically if i do understand correct you want the sum for each distinct set.

> So not 34 + 34 + 34 + 23 + 23 + 23 + 43 + 43 + 43 ... BUT 34 + 23 + 43

In order to that you need to trick MySQL with the following query :

```
SELECT 
SUM(tot.invalid_votes) AS total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT QV, invalid_votes FROM `results`) tot
```

This will return the SUM of the *Distinct* values based on QV field.

Table :

```
QV  invalid_votes
0544    5
0544    5
0544    5
0545    6
0545    6
```

based on the database information you provided i get the following result **11**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(f3) FROM `tablename` GROUP BY f2, f3
```

Comment: Nope, ain't working, Shouldn't this give me one result? I'm getting More that I have Group by f2

Comment: Is there e way to get SUM of SUM

Comment: @Flakerim - the `sum` of a `sum` would still just be a `sum`.  You don't need to re-aggregate it if you make clear what you want in the first place.  Can you clarify your original question?

Comment: Right, I will try to explain: f2 is unique number. if I get grouped by f2 I got what I need but not sum. So I need first to get gruouped by f2 and get the sum of f3.

Comment: The try to do a subselect like
`SELECT f3 FROM table GROUP BY f2`
And then sum f3 from the subselect.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to get the sum of the three different values is

```
Select sum (distinct f3) from yourtable
```

I hope it makes sense to you, because I'm still trying to figure out what you want.

Comment: its risky to do it like that since you cannot be sure the numbers with the same value are linked to the same 'grouped values' of the f2 table... but you are right, hard to understand what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pastebin you posted,

this should work

```
SELECT QV, SUM(invalid_votes) FROM `results` GROUP BY QV
```

I get the following result

```
QV      SUM(invalid_votes)
0544    15
0545    12
```

Comment: Yes it does, but How can i sum SUM(invalid_votes) so at the end I got only one value